# Advanced syntax: "0[constructor][constructor]()()" - How does it works to evaluate code?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

In a code obfuscator algorithm I see one step using this syntax:

```
0["constructor"]["constructor"](
    0["constructor"]["constructor"](
        "return \"alert()\""
    )();
)();
```

My knowledge of javascript help me no more ...

```
typeof 0                               => number
typeof 0["constructor"]                => function
typeof 0["constructor"]["constructor"] => function
```

Please, can you explain **what does the js interpreter do to 'handle' this code** ? 
I cannot understand in which way could it work !

And: **what does the ending "()" mean ?** I cannot understand the syntax

I tried to play with firebug js console

Executing

```
0["constructor"]["constructor"](
    "return \"alert()\""
)();
```

The console outputs `"alert()"`, (with double quotes)

I was thinked it was equivalent to an eval, but it's not. Running this:

```
eval( "return \"alert()\"" );
```

simply causes a `SyntaxError: return not in function`.

Executing the first snippet of this question, is fully equivalent to simply execute a `alert()`, so I understand that *inner* code think the text is like a function body and execute it, so the *inner* is returning `"alert()"`; the outer read this last string and thinks it's a function body, so execute the code, and result is that the alert is triggerred.

But, I repeat. **What does it mean the syntax ? What are usefull for the "()" at the end?**

```
0["constructor"]["constructor"](
    "some code to be evaluted"
)();
```

Comment: [Read about dot and bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators). *"What are usefull for the "()" at the end?"* I don't know what that is supposed to mean, but the `()` calls the function that is reference before it. In this case `0["constructor"]["constructor"]`, which us `Function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is finding the [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), calling it to create a new function with the argument as the code for the function's body, then invoking that function immediately:

```
Function("Some code to be evaluated")()
```

It does this twice, once with the `String` literal `"return \"alert()\""`, then again with the `return` value from the 1st function as the body for the 2nd.

```
var result = Function("Some code to be evaluated")()
Function(result)()
```

And, it gets `Function` by 1st finding `Number` from `0`, then `Function` from `Number`:

```
console.log(0["constructor"] === Number); // true
console.log(Number["constructor"] === Function); // true
```

Comment: I followed the link. I read this signature ```new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ... argN]],] functionBody)```so the last string is handled as function body (I'm happy I've guessed it) ? Right ? And yhy using two times ["constructor"]["constructor"] ?

But why the "()" at the end ? Is it for an immediate execution ?

Comment: @realtebo Yes and yes. :) The argument is will be the `functionBody`. And the 1st set of parenthesis are for calling the constructor, then the 2nd, just `()`, are for calling the new function created by the constructor.

Comment: @realtebo The 2 uses of `["constructor"]` are just a round-about way of referencing `Function`. The 1st will return `0`'s constructor, which is `Number`. Then, the 2nd will return `Number`'s constructor, which is `Function`.