# What's happening in this code?

Tags: javascript

```
eval (function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c]=k[c]||c}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}(function(z){var a="0%3Y%7Z%5W%5Y%3W0%3Y%7W3%3V%2W%2W0%2X%24%24%24%24%3V%28%21%5W%5Y%2W%22%22%29%5W0%5Y%2X2%24%3V%2W%2W0%2X%241%241%3V%28%21%5W%5Y%2W%22%22%29%5W0%5Y%2X1%241%3V%2W%2W0%2X%241%24%24%3V%28%7W%7Y%2W%22%22%29%5W0%5Y%2X%24%241%24%3V%280%5W0%5Y%2W%22%22%29%5W0%5Y%2X1%24%24%3V%2W%2W0%2X%24%24%241%3V%28%21%22%22%2W%22%22%29%5W0%5Y%2X%242%3V%2W%2W0%2X%241%24%3V%2W%2W0%2X%24%242%3V%28%7W%7Y%2W%22%22%29%5W0%5Y%2X%24%241%3V%2W%2W0%2X%24%24%24%3V%2W%2W0%2X%243%3V%2W%2W0%2X%242%24%3V%2W%2W0%7Y%3W0.%241%3Y%280.%241%3Y0%2W%22%22%29%5W0.%241%24%5Y%2W%280.1%24%3Y0.%241%5W0.2%24%5Y%29%2W%280.%24%24%3Y%280.%24%2W%22%22%29%5W0.2%24%5Y%29%2W%28%28%210%29%2W%22%22%29%5W0.1%24%24%5Y%2W%280.2%3Y0.%241%5W0.%24%241%5Y%29%2W%280.%24%3Y%28%21%22%22%2W%22%22%29%5W0.2%24%5Y%29%2W%280.1%3Y%28%21%22%22%2W%22%22%29%5W0.1%241%5Y%29%2W0.%241%5W0.%241%24%5Y%2W0.2%2W0.1%24%2W0.%24%3W0.%24%24%3Y0.%24%2W%28%21%22%22%2W%22%22%29%5W0.1%24%24%5Y%2W0.2%2W0.1%2W0.%24%2W0.%24%24%3W0.%24%3Y%280.3%29%5W0.%241%5Y%5W0.%241%5Y%3W0.%24%280.%24%280.%24%24%2W%22%5X%22%22%2W%22%5X%5X%22%2W0.2%24%2W0.%24%241%2W0.%24%24%24%2W%22%5X%5X%22%2W0.2%24%2W0.%241%24%2W0.2%24%2W%22%5X%5X%22%2W0.2%24%2W0.%241%24%2W0.%24%241%2W0.%24%241%24%2W0.1%24%2W%22%5X%5X%22%2W0.2%24%2W0.%24%241%2W0.%24%24%24%2W%22.%22%2W0.2%2W0.1%24%2W%22%5X%5X%22%2W0.2%24%2W0.%241%24%2W0.1%24%24%2W0.%24%24%241%2W%22%5X%5X%22%2W0.2%24%2W0.%241%24%2W0.%24%241%2W%22%3Y%5X%5X%5X%22%22%2W0.%24%24%241%2W0.%24%241%24%2W0.%24%24%241%2W0.%242%2W0.%24%24%241%2W0.%241%24%2W0.%24%241%24%2W0.3%2W0.%24%24%24%24%2W0.%242%24%2W0.%243%2W0.%24%241%24%2W0.%241%241%2W0.%241%24%24%2W0.%241%24%24%2W0.%243%2W%22%5X%5X%5X%22%3W%22%2W%22%5X%22%22%29%28%29%29%28%29%3W";return decodeURIComponent(a.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,function(c){return String.fromCharCode((c<="Z"?90:122)>=(c=c.charCodeAt(0)+z)?c:c-26);}));}(5),4,4,('j^_^__^___'+'').split("^"),0,{}))
```

It's a long nasty code; is this generating some kind of token? What is eval?

Then the following code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b=[ function(v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49){return 'eab06fe04deb99232cb1b02d276577f3d78c6a1e0903c35067b9ce2716ba1bf29c548037';}, function(v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49){return v62e7c068cf40fb716b0a4022a6907ddb.createElement(v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49);}, function(v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49){return v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49[0].getContext(v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49[1]);}, function(v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49){return v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49[0].text=v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49[1];}, function(v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49){return null;}, function(v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49){'9a3d6127374af09c22015bf3ede3ac00a36e3ec68e2aee86080fc6e93dc20b614d326001';}, function(v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49){return 'c1a38b8a671f58b20d4079b68d6533216db2a3644fd0e81a93f0b42abf77047ac4811a76';}, function(v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49){v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49..style.visibility = 'visible';return v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49;}, function(v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49){vcd9dcd7c15919eec0841be8fc645800a.onload=v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49}, function(v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49){vcd9dcd7c15919eec0841be8fc645800a.src=v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49;}, new Function("v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49","return unescape(decodeURIComponent(window.atob(v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49)))"), function(v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49){vbe3ae157bcaf01bd49ec5a9b228e92fb=new Function('v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49',v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[10](vb62882d32e1d25a47dad7ec52996d6d1[v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49]));return vbe3ae157bcaf01bd49ec5a9b228e92fb;}]; vd59121fb3cac08aa0a8b6824930bbfc8=[0,255,2]; vb62882d32e1d25a47dad7ec52996d6d1=[ 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJ2NhbnZhcyclM0I=', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJ25vbmUnJTNC', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJzJkJyUzQg==', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJ3NjcmlwdCclM0I=', '', 'vb6858e683e12b2a6fd12b7492286d482', 'v61759e13ee66390eebceea42e1bf393f', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwJ2RhdGElM0FpbWFnZSUyRnBuZyUzQmJhc2U2NCUyQyclM0I=', '', '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', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwdjYyZTdjMDY4Y2Y0MGZiNzE2YjBhNDAyMmE2OTA3ZGRiLmdldEVsZW1lbnRCeUlkKHY5YzFiYzAxZTY3NDUyNjUwMDVhYmRkMGNkYTg1NWE0OSklM0I=', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwZG9jdW1lbnQ=', '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', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwbmV3JTIwSW1hZ2UoKSUzQg==', 'cmV0dXJuJTIwU3RyaW5nLmZyb21DaGFyQ29kZSh2OWMxYmMwMWU2NzQ1MjY1MDA1YWJkZDBjZGE4NTVhNDkpJTNC']; v62e7c068cf40fb716b0a4022a6907ddb=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[11](11)(); v82bdb1dbff37fafb81c17c858f505f30=new Function('v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49',v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[10](vb62882d32e1d25a47dad7ec52996d6d1[10])); vcd9dcd7c15919eec0841be8fc645800a=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[7](v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[11](13)()); v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[8](function(){ v898cf141a0292375690dc2d870e9ea4c=v82bdb1dbff37fafb81c17c858f505f30(vb62882d32e1d25a47dad7ec52996d6d1[5]); v4980df2eeb49376354de7adc49b8c515=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[1](v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[11](0)()); v4980df2eeb49376354de7adc49b8c515.width=vcd9dcd7c15919eec0841be8fc645800a.width; v4980df2eeb49376354de7adc49b8c515.height=vcd9dcd7c15919eec0841be8fc645800a.height; v4980df2eeb49376354de7adc49b8c515.style.display=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[11](1)();vfabd8e64496a65104b22e87785375ec2=vb62882d32e1d25a47dad7ec52996d6d1[4]; v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[2]([v4980df2eeb49376354de7adc49b8c515,v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[11](2)()]); v045c82746058eaa96f8c3582434b9958=new Function('v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49',v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[10](vb62882d32e1d25a47dad7ec52996d6d1[14])); v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55.drawImage(vcd9dcd7c15919eec0841be8fc645800a, vd59121fb3cac08aa0a8b6824930bbfc8[0], vd59121fb3cac08aa0a8b6824930bbfc8[0]); v54778c45d9eaae22ace866c4620fbcf0=v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55.getImageData(vd59121fb3cac08aa0a8b6824930bbfc8[0], vd59121fb3cac08aa0a8b6824930bbfc8[0],v4980df2eeb49376354de7adc49b8c515.width,v4980df2eeb49376354de7adc49b8c515.height); v032b25122768323ba3ff216bac88e630=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[11](12)(); (new Function(v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[10](vfabd8e64496a65104b22e87785375ec2)))(); vb6858e683e12b2a6fd12b7492286d482=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55);vcd9dcd7c15919eec0841be8fc645800a=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](vb6858e683e12b2a6fd12b7492286d482);v4980df2eeb49376354de7adc49b8c515=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v4980df2eeb49376354de7adc49b8c515);v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v54778c45d9eaae22ace866c4620fbcf0);v54778c45d9eaae22ace866c4620fbcf0=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55);vc8950002beb8fc5e3f11a7a8894da368=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55);vfabd8e64496a65104b22e87785375ec2=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55);vc786e14ccce1ea9c3b6888c71d833ba5=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55);ve26c4b3b719e771da0cfee9dc4cf8b4d=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55);vb6858e683e12b2a6fd12b7492286d482=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55);v5071b744d29861099da6c21c29c07390=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55);v62e7c068cf40fb716b0a4022a6907ddb=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55);v032b25122768323ba3ff216bac88e630=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55);vb62882d32e1d25a47dad7ec52996d6d1=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55);vd59121fb3cac08aa0a8b6824930bbfc8=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55);v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55);v9c1bc01e6745265005abdd0cda855a49=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v898cf141a0292375690dc2d870e9ea4c);v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[4](v420e61e2ef6aa1c21c2096af36ec9f55); }); v032b25122768323ba3ff216bac88e630=v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[9](v06b9e817c4ddcf60fbd82113f8c1f49b[11](7)()+vb62882d32e1d25a47dad7ec52996d6d1[9]);
$("body").mouseup(function(a){($(a.target).hasClass("logobrandOutsideplayer")||$(a.target).hasClass("logocontainer")||$(a.target).hasClass("title")||"videooverlay"==$(a.target).attr("id"))&&window.popAdsLoaded&&$("#videooverlay,.title,.logocontainer").hide()});
function tw(w,i){if(w==null){$.post("https://tt2.openload.co/r3/f",{"popurl":"lost","poppool":"lost","position":7+i});}}
 </script>
```

I'm interested to know how v is generated.
and what are they; since they seem to be html attribute it can be seen using .src

```
D7R5txI4
```

^ I'm trying to understand if that long nasty token code encrypts the long token that starts with v and results to `D7R5txI4`

Comment: This is probably some minified / obfuscated code. If you want to put effort in decrypting that, good luck ;-) It is possible (obviously), but will take a lot of effort. There are many such minification/obfuscation tools, like [this](https://javascriptobfuscator.com/).

Comment: The second line seems to have syntax errors and does not execute. Have you pasted it correctly? Specifically the double dot in `..style.visibility` and there is no `]` to match the initial `[`.

Answer (score 2):

The first line ultimately executes:

```
window.token="ede4e5d0f98dabb8"
```

The second line seems unrelated. I cannot tell you what it does because it is incomplete.

To work out the first line, change the eval to console.log. Now execute it ( I used nodeJs) and you see what it is trying to eval:

```
j=~[];j={___:++j,$$$$:(![]+"")[j],__$:++j,$_$_:(![]+"")[j],_$_:++j,$_$$:({}+"")[j],$$_$:(j[j]+"")[j],_$$:++j,$$$_:(!""+"")[j],$__:++j,$_$:++j,$$__:({}+"")[j],$$_:++j,$$$:++j,$___:++j,$__$:++j};j.$_=(j.$_=j+"")[j.$_$]+(j._$=j.$_[j.__$])+(j.$$=(j.$+"")[j.__$])+((!j)+"")[j._$$]+(j.__=j.$_[j.$$_])+(j.$=(!""+"")[j.__$])+(j._=(!""+"")[j._$_])+j.$_[j.$_$]+j.__+j._$+j.$;j.$$=j.$+(!""+"")[j._$$]+j.__+j._+j.$+j.$$;j.$=(j.___)[j.$_][j.$_];j.$(j.$(j.$$+"\""+"\\"+j.__$+j.$$_+j.$$$+"\\"+j.__$+j.$_$+j.__$+"\\"+j.__$+j.$_$+j.$$_+j.$$_$+j._$+"\\"+j.__$+j.$$_+j.$$$+"."+j.__+j._$+"\\"+j.__$+j.$_$+j._$$+j.$$$_+"\\"+j.__$+j.$_$+j.$$_+"=\\\""+j.$$$_+j.$$_$+j.$$$_+j.$__+j.$$$_+j.$_$+j.$$_$+j.___+j.$$$$+j.$__$+j.$___+j.$$_$+j.$_$_+j.$_$$+j.$_$$+j.$___+"\\\";"+"\"")())();
```

Now when we format it we see it is 6 lines:

```
j = ~[];
j = { ___: ++j, $$$$: (![] + "")[j], __$: ++j, $_$_: (![] + "")[j], _$_: ++j, $_$$: ({} + "")[j], $$_$: (j[j] + "")[j], _$$: ++j, $$$_: (!"" + "")[j], $__: ++j, $_$: ++j, $$__: ({} + "")[j], $$_: ++j, $$$: ++j, $___: ++j, $__$: ++j };
j.$_ = (j.$_ = j + "")[j.$_$] + (j._$ = j.$_[j.__$]) + (j.$$ = (j.$ + "")[j.__$]) + ((!j) + "")[j._$$] + (j.__ = j.$_[j.$$_]) + (j.$ = (!"" + "")[j.__$]) + (j._ = (!"" + "")[j._$_]) + j.$_[j.$_$] + j.__ + j._$ + j.$;
j.$$ = j.$ + (!"" + "")[j._$$] + j.__ + j._ + j.$ + j.$$;
j.$ = (j.___)[j.$_][j.$_];
j.$(j.$(j.$$ + "\"" + "\\" + j.__$ + j.$$_ + j.$$$ + "\\" + j.__$ + j.$_$ + j.__$ + "\\" + j.__$ + j.$_$ + j.$$_ + j.$$_$ + j._$ + "\\" + j.__$ + j.$$_ + j.$$$ + "." + j.__ + j._$ + "\\" + j.__$ + j.$_$ + j._$$ + j.$$$_ + "\\" + j.__$ + j.$_$ + j.$$_ + "=\\\"" + j.$$$_ + j.$$_$ + j.$$$_ + j.$__ + j.$$$_ + j.$_$ + j.$$_$ + j.___ + j.$$$$ + j.$__$ + j.$___ + j.$$_$ + j.$_$_ + j.$_$$ + j.$_$$ + j.$___ + "\\\";" + "\"")())();
```

Executing the first 4 lines, we see it has created an object `j`:

```
    j = { ___: 0,
        '$$$$': 'f',
        '__$': 1,
        '$_$_': 'a',
        '_$_': 2,
        '$_$$': 'b',
        '$$_$': 'd',
        '_$$': 3,
        '$$$_': 'e',
        '$__': 4,
        '$_$': 5,
        '$$__': 'c',
        '$$_': 6,
        '$$$': 7,
        '$___': 8,
        '$__$': 9,
        '$_': 'constructor',
        '_$': 'o',
        '$$': 'return',
        __: 't',
        '$': [Function: Function],
        _: 'u' }
```

Now we can see that the 5th line `j.$ = (j.___)[j.$_][j.$_];` is actually

```
j.$ = (0)['constructor']['constructor'];
```

Which makes j.$ a function `f` where `f(string)()` does the same as `eval(string)`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635387)

So the final line is effectively

```
f(f(string)())()
```

and when we evaluate the string the by running the expression we see it is:

```
string = 'return"\\167\\151\\156do\\167.to\\153e\\156=\\"ede4e5d0f98dabb8\\";"'
```

So we are `eval`ing a function that returns the string

```
return"\167\151\156do\167.to\153e\156=\"ede4e5d0f98dabb8\";"
```

and this evaluates

```
window.token="ede4e5d0f98dabb8"
```

Comment: So, I'm assuming D7R5txI4 has nothing to do with the token?

Comment: Well answered! Thanks!

Comment: I've added the full js for the second line if you can take a quick look for it for me =) @James